# How can I display ë character in the url?

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, ascii

I have an url that contains this `ë` character. Is there any way so that I can display as `ë` in front end, but in backend it can be converted to ASCII value `%C3%AB` of this character. 
When you view this question particular page url will display `ë` character. So I want same thing to be display. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'd do good to look at the HTML for this page then:

```
<a href="/questions/38720183/how-can-i-display-%c3%ab-character-in-the-url">
```

You must use the correctly URL-encoded version, `%c3%ab`. The browser *may* then decide to render it as "ë". That's entirely up to the browser, and it won't do it for *all* characters, specifically it won't decode particular lookalike characters which can be used to spoof a URL to *look* identical to another URL but actually be different.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which is

> a mechanism for encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier
>   (URI) under certain circumstances. Although it is known as URL
>   encoding it is, in fact, used more generally within the main Uniform
>   Resource Identifier (URI) set, which includes both Uniform Resource
>   Locator (URL) and Uniform Resource Name (URN). As such, it is also
>   used in the preparation of data of the
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type, as is often used in the
>   submission of HTML form data in HTTP requests.

There is a website http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ that will do it for you

Comment: there's also a good article here for obj-c/swift developers http://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-percent-encode-a-url-string/